# Introspection in Java

Tags: java, object, introspection

I have a stack of Objects, in this stack I push ClassA and ClassB objects.
I have a method which must return objects from this stack

```
public Object method(Stack s){
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    stack.push(a);
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    stack.push(b);
    while(stack has two elements) stack.pop();
    return stack.pop()// I return the last element
}
```

the problem is: when I call this method instanceof doesn't work, it can't tell anymore ClassA from ClassB

```
Object o = method(s);
if ( o instanceof ClassA){
    //do something
} else if (o instanceof ClassB) {
    //do something else
}
```

Inside method(Stack s) instanceof works, outside doesn't, but the toString() method works fine, it return the proper String for each class.

Comment: Are you getting some exception? Or any compiler error? Can you post the code where you are doing instanceof check? the method?

Comment: Are you certain that the method doesn't return null?

Comment: `while(stack has two elements) `seems to be quite strange as well

Comment: Yeah, it should be `while (stack has two or more than two elements)`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes, I'm certain, the toString method works. Thomas and Rohit, your suggestion is right, I will correct the code. I can't post all the code but I'm going to post a simple example in a few minutes.

Comment: If the magic while is something like while (!stack.isEmpty()) then when calling return stack.pop() you will get an EmptyStackException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few scenarios where your introspection code may not work as you expect:

- If `o` is `null`, the `instanceof` operator returns `false`.  The `null` value is not an instance of any type ... according to the JLS.
- If `ClassB` is a subtype of `classA`, then `o instanceof ClassA` will return `true` for an instance of `ClassB`.
- If you are doing something complicated with classloaders, it is possible to load the same ".class" file with different class loaders.  If you do that, you will run into the problems that the two "copies" of the class actually have different types ... and `instanceof` will return `false`.  (This behaviour is also specified in the JLS.)

The last case can be particularly confusing, because when you look at the names of the two classes they will be the same.  However `class1.equals(class2)` or `class1 == class2` will give you the definitive answer about whether two classes are actually the same.

Comment: It was an error in my code, thank you btw for the explanation